# Fragments observing livedata forever

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

The problem: I'm facing a problem with fragments and shared **viewmodel** **LiveData** ... The problem that is there is a **FragmentA** that update data in shared **viewmodel** and observe for it's changes then display the result for the user inside **FragmentA**, **FragmentA** can launch new instance of **FragmentA** to get new data and display it so the fragment launch it self and old instance gets added to the back stack, until here nothing is wrong the new instance updates **LiveData** in **viewModel** and displays the new data perfectly the problem that is when i **popUpBackstack()** return to **FragmentA** old instance the data displays in it is the data that new **FragmentA** instance gets it which means that old **FragmentA** instance still observing the data even if i remove the observers ... this is general overview about the problem now i will show you fragments structure, the code and what the solution's that i'v tried.

Expected behavior: what i want to achieve is that when **FragmentA** launch it self and gets added to back stack stop observing the data in **viewModel** and when i back to it displays the old data that's all.

- Fragment structure: i use one activity to hold all the fragments ... **MainActivity** have **FindMoviesFragment** inside it there is a **viewPager** which holds **FragmentMovies** which launches **MovieDetailsFragment** and inside it there is **ViewPager** also which holds the fragments that displays the data from **MoviesViewModel** it will get clear when you see the code below.

This code shows how **MovieDetailsFragment** initialize **MoviesViewModel** and updates data in viewmodel:

```
 class MovieDetailsFragment:Fragment(R.layout.movie_details_fragment) {

    private val args: MovieDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private val  fragmentList:ArrayList<Fragment> by lazy {
        arrayListOf(MovieDetailsOneFragment(args.movieId), MovieDetailsTwoFragment(),MovieDetailsThreeFragment())
    }
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: ViewPagerAdapter
    private lateinit var moviesViewModel: MoviesViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)
        
        //these two lines updates the data in viewmodel
        moviesViewModel.getMovieDetails(args.movieId)
        moviesViewModel.changeMovieID(args.movieId)

    }

}

//---------------------MoviesViewModel------------------//

class MoviesViewModel constructor(private val repo:Repository):ViewModel() {

     private val _currentMovieDetails = MutableLiveData<Resource<MovieDetails>>()
    val currentMovieDetails :LiveData<Resource<MovieDetails>>
        get() = _currentMovieDetails

    fun getMovieDetails(movieID:Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _currentMovieDetails.postValue(Resource.loading(null))

        val result = repo.getMovieDetails(movieID)
   
        if(result.isSuccessful){
            _currentMovieDetails.postValue(Resource.success(result.body()))
           
        }
        else{
            _currentMovieDetails.postValue(Resource.error(result.errorBody().toString(),null))
        }

    }

}
```

And inside **MovieDetailsOne** which is inside viewpager in **MovieDetailsFragment** i observe the data like this:

```
class MovieDetailsOneFragment(private val movieId: Int):Fragment(R.layout.movie_details_one) {

    private lateinit var moviesViewModel:MoviesViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //this is how i define viewModel(global scope)
        moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        //in this method i observe on changes in currentMovieDetils liveData
        subscribeToObservers()
        //i try to call this from on create and nothing changes too

    }
}
```

Now What i tried is the following:

-Loacal scope for fragments

```
//Define viewModel like this in MovieDetilsFragment

moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)

//And in MovieDetailsOne like this
moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)

//and this doesn't work MovieDetailsOne don't observe any changes
```

-Observe once extinction function:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
   observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
       override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
           observer.onChanged(t)
           removeObserver(this)
       }
   })
}

//and this doesn't work MovieDetailsOne don't observe first time it's lanches
```

I know i took so long to explain :D but I'm trying to give you clear idea and sorry for you time <3 ... if you want any additional information about the code or the problem comment down below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i achieve the behavior that i want by doing some steps which is:

Attach **ViewPager** childs  using **childFragmentManager** which means that android will treat viewpager fragments as childs for viewPager holder:

```
//instead of doing this
pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(activity?.supportragmentManager, lifecycle, fragmentList)

//do this
pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle, fragmentList)
```

Define local  **viewModel** for parent fragment like this:

```
//instead of doing this
moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)

//do this
moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)
```

Define parent fragment scope **viewModel** in childs fragment:

```
//instead of doing this
moviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)

//do this
private val moviesViewModel:MoviesViewModel by viewModels(
        {requireParentFragment()}
    )
```

by doing these steps parent fragment will stop observing data when it's destroyed and child fragments also.